# Does db4o (at version 8) still acquire complete db file lock on write

Tags: database, db4o

I read this here : http://developer.db4o.com/Forums/tabid/98/aft/5027/Default.aspx#20510 
The link is from 2008 I am hoping they have come up with a better way by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still does. The db4o core still uses a single lock to protect its operations. Nothing has changed about that.

Comment: Marked as answered. An official link would be useful though.

Comment: Hmm, I cant think of a document which states that db4o behaves that way (except the source-code).